# Dockerfile VOLUME source not exists

Tags: docker

i run docker images with

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name jenkins jenkins
```

then i run

```
docker inspect jenkins
```

result:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "fca04563bd5c57e5a3765e0af376c3d175e32deed20fe3bbf7204f92f61d579a",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/fca04563bd5c57e5a3765e0af376c3d175e32deed20fe3bbf7204f92f61d579a/_data",
            "Destination": "/opt/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ]
```

but, while i try to cd to source, it turns out file not found.where am i wrong?
i run docker instance on my MAC

Comment: You shouldn't try to access the content of named volumes like that.  If you need access to it on the host, delete and recreate the container with a `-v` option specifying a host directory for that container directory.

Comment: i known what u said,but i'm still confusing with why VOLUME does't work. from my opinion, if i use VOLUME in Dockerfile instead of using -v option specifying a hostdirectory for that container directory. Docker will create a directory in "/var/lib/docker/volumes/XXXXXX/_data" . am i wrony?